# PHP failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php

I have this script on server, and he worked a year.

```
$json_object = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . 
'/feed?fields=permalink_url&limit=5&access_token=' . $access_token);
```

Now hosting provider make something changes at server side and script doesnt work (on local server all continues to work). 
I have next errors:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(***): failed to open stream: Permissions denied in ***.php on line 18

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ***.php on line 26

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ***.php on line 28
```

Im rewrite this script, with using curl instead file_get_contents:

```
// 1. init
$ch = curl_init();  
// 2. params
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/****/feed?fields=permalink_url&limit=5&access_token=****");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
// 3. get result  
$output = curl_exec($ch);  
 echo $output;
 if ($output === FALSE) {  
    //Maybe error
    echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);  
    return;  
}  
// 4. close connection 
curl_close($ch);
```

Result:

```
cURL Error: couldn't connect to host
```

How to find a way to define this problem?

Comment: did you check that is a valid URL in the browser?

Comment: Do a step-by-step (...and stick to cURL imho). First try a connection to `https://graph.facebook.com` and complete each time you get a valid request. If it already stops at the 'basic' url, then your hosting provider may have blocked the access or facebook has because you did too many queries...

Comment: of course. in browser all works, and on local server (xampp) all works too

Comment: im not send a many requests. site auditory is 20-50 uniques users per day and in request limit for 5 posts

Comment: I think that the hoster changed in php.ini option - allow_url_fopen